# User accepting edits that should not be accepted

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, moderation

Should you report users to diamond mods if they accept and edit that should not be accepted?

In this situation the edit was reject anyway, but should any further action be taken?

[Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5331348)

*IMO - I would like to do everything possible to stop robo-reviewers.*

Comment: Relevant meta thread: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265917/should-we-be-able-to-flag-suggested-edits

Comment: Flag if you looked into the issue and found clear proof of a pattern. Include your research after a few choice words to describe why you flag.